# ajax load image not working second time on popup jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on site where i show fancybox for contact us form.i submit form using ajax.on process state i show ajax loading image.On first click it show the image but clicking again image doesn't show.My ajax code is this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm()
{

  jQuery(".ajax-content").show();



    var str = jQuery( "form" ).serialize();
       jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url:  'myurl',
        data:  str,
        format: "json",
        beforeSend: function( xhr ) { alert('hi'); jQuery(".ajax-content").show();},
        success: function(data) {

            var obj =  JSON.parse(data);

            if( obj[0] === 'error')
            {

                 jQuery("#error").html(obj[1]);
                  jQuery(".loading-gif").hide();
             }else{
            jQuery(".loading-gif").hide();
                    jQuery("#result").html(obj[1]);
                     setTimeout(function () {
                     jQuery.fancybox.close();
                 }, 2500);
                    }
        } 

      });    
}

</script>
```

`ajax-content` class is that div contains ajax image
Any help or pointing to error will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the image is hidden the second time. Can you try

```
 beforeSend: function( xhr ) { 
    alert('hi'); 
    jQuery(".loading-gif").show();
    jQuery(".ajax-content").show();
 },
```